# how to call method after 2 minutes in background

Tags: java, android, service

i need to call a method after 2 minutes. i have tried handler and timer but when app close then it doesn't work. then i have call timer in service and start service on button click and stop service after 2 minutes. it works but problem is sometime service calls itself. below is my code.

MyService class

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.d("message", "start");
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d("message", "finish");

            callMyMethod();
            stopService(new Intent(MyService.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }.start();
}
```

MainActivity class from where i start service.

```
stopService(new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class));
startService(new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class));
```

Manifest

```
<service android:name="MyService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"/>
```

NOTE: I WANT TO CALL SERVICE ONLY ON BUTTON CLICK AND STOP SERVICE AFTER 2 MINUTES.
please need help to solve this issue or If there is other good solution other than services.

**Updated: if network response in not success how can i handle to retry.**

MyService class

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.d("mess", "start");
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d("mess", "finish");

            selectDriverForJOb();
            stopSelf();//(new Intent(MyService.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

private void selectDriverForJOb() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Login_credentials", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String user_id = sharedPreferences.getString("userID", null);
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    APIServices_interface selectDriver_interface = retrofit.create(APIServices_interface.class);
    Call<SelectDriverforJobResult> call = null;
    try {
        call = selectDriver_interface.selectDriverforJob(user_id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (call != null) {
        try {
            call.enqueue(new Callback<SelectDriverforJobResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<SelectDriverforJobResult> call, Response<SelectDriverforJobResult> response) {
                    SelectDriverforJobResult selectDriver = response.body();
                    String message = selectDriver.getMessage();
                    if(!(message.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))){

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<SelectDriverforJobResult> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("mess : ", "Error Updating ");
                    //want to retry
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: use async task In async task use handler or countdown timer

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod its not duplicate. i have checked that question already. that didn't solve my issue.

Comment: can you explain **service calls itself**? From where `startService` is called?

Comment: @VinodMaurya calling service from main activity on button click.

Comment: What if user click the button for first time and service started and close the app ? Do you still need to perform task after 2 minutes or not ?

Comment: @ADM yes service will called after 2 minutes even if app is close or open.

Comment: Ok !  So Service is not the solution for this scenario as i have already mentioned in the answer below . This is clearly a use case of `AlarmManager` or `JobShedular`. Since you need Internet connection so its better to go with `JobShedular`. You can try `WorkManager` its a wrapper around `JobShedular` and works with all OS versions .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override `onStartCommand`  in service and return `START_NOT_STICKY`  it will not restart the

```
public void onStartCommand()
{
     return START_NOT_STICKY
}
```

and use `stopSelf()` insted of `stopService(new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class));`

Comment: i have updated my code. please check it now. how to handle if response from server is fail.

Comment: kindly accept the answer if it solves your problem @AsifUllah

Answer (score 2):

Your Service will not run after app close, Read [background restriction](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background). 
And this is not really a `Service` use case.

The solution can be to your problem is [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) . Set an alarm for exact after 2 minutes and your Receiver willget called when its triggered . Before using `AlarmManger` give a read to `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` and `setExact()`.

Alternatively you can also use `WorkManager` to set a Exact Job . But This will be an overkill if you do not need `Job Constraints`.  So if your work does not depends of any Constraints like Network connection or other you can go with `AlarmManger`.

**PS**:- If your task depends on a Network connection then you should go with `WorkManager`. Read [Schedule tasks with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries./architecture/workmanager) .

Comment: yes i make a network request in my method.and i am retrieving a message in response. i want to stop service if response is "success" or again send request if response is not success. 
Please can you edit my code how to use WorkManager?

Comment: `how to use WorkManager?` can be a very broad answer . You should go through the link above and follow some tutorials [Sample](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-workmanager). Its not that hard to use and understand just go through the sample.